# Не могу разобраться как сделать лабу DataViewGrid

Tags: c#, c++

Есть DataViewGrid он заполнялся с texbox-ов, как мне сделать заполнение со второй формы, которую я вызвал, но как передать с формы 2 переменные?
Форма 2 теперь будет иметь такие элементы вместо textbox.
Не пойму как сделать

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
   private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
                int m = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
                this.dataGridView1.RowCount = m + 1;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }
```

В форме один у меня код который считал P из положительных строк, но его я буду переделывать в матрицу

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int n = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
            int m = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
            int k;
            int p = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                k = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value) <= 0)
                    {
                        k = 0; break;

                    }
                    if (k != 0) p++;
               
            }
            label1.Text="P = " + p.ToString();
```

Как сделать чтобы при нажатии заполнить на button1 заполнялся dataviewgrid1 на форме 1. У меня пока все плохо

Form1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinAPP
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
           
        }

       public class Data
        {
            public static int Value1 { get; set; }
            public static int Value2 { get; set; }
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                int n = Data.Value1;
                int m = Data.Value2;
                dataGridView1.ColumnCount = n;
                this.dataGridView1.RowCount = m + 1;
                button2.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView2.Rows.Clear();
            int n = Data.Value1;
            int m = Data.Value2;
            int k;
            int p = 0;
            float[,] array = new float[n, m];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                k = 1;

                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    array[i, j] = Convert.ToSingle(dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value);
                }
            }
            dataGridView2.ColumnCount = n;
            this.dataGridView2.RowCount = m + 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                k = 1;
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                    if (array[i, j] <= 0)
                    {
                        k = 0; break;

                    }
                if (k != 0) p++;

            }
            label1.Text = "P = " + p.ToString();
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[i].Value = array[i, j];
                }
            }
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 fr2 = new Form2();
            fr2.Show();
        }

        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WinAPP
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form1.Data.Value1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Value);
            Form1.Data.Value2 = Convert.ToInt32(column.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Нужно что бы считало P и на DataViewGrid, после заполнения. Но у меня выдает ошибку в if(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value <= 0) что то с object.
P нужно чтобы потом выполнить сортировку матрицы

Comment: `dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value` - возвращает тип `object`, который вы сравнивате с числом.  Сначала оберните это выражение в `int.Parse()`, перед этим получив строку методом `ToString()`. Так же в С# нет неявного приведения чисел к bool, поэтому `if (k)` замените на `if (k!=0)`.

Comment: @SmorcIRL не получается int.Parse(), тоже ошибка. или я не правильно делаю, так как не особо владею #с

Comment: `if (int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString()) <= 0)`. Можете ещё просто приводить к `int`, если уверены что только числа будете хранить.

Comment: @SmorcIRL спасибо, если не затруднит последний вопрос, а как обратиться к переменным с кнопки  button2_Click n, m . Чтобы они не были локальными в button 3, тут тоже ссылки работают?

Comment: Можете получить их так же как в методе `button2_Click`, либо сохранять в поля класса

Comment: Один и тот же код, считает в #с почему то по строкам

в c++ по столбцам

Comment: Не понял вас, что вы хотите посчитать?

Comment: @SmorcIRL уже исправил, так что спасибо огромное за помощь)